# Compare two rows on a loop for on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe where I want to determinate if the column A is greater than column B and if column C is greater of column B. In case it is smaller, I want to change that value for 0.

```
d = {'A': [6, 8, 10, 1, 3], 'B': [4, 9, 12, 0, 2], 'C': [3, 14, 11, 4, 9] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I have tried this with the np.where and it is working:

```
df[B] = np.where(df[A] > df[B], 0, df[B])
df[C] = np.where(df[B] > df[C], 0, df[C])
```

However, I have a huge amount of columns and I want to know if there is any way to do this without writing each comparation separately. For example, a loop for.

Thanks

Comment: kindly post the expected output dataframe

Comment: should the final value in cell 0/C be 0 or 3?

Comment: It should be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with different ouput, because is compared original columns with [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and set less like `0` values to `0` by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df1 = df.mask(df.diff(axis=1).lt(0), 0)
print (df1)
    A   B   C
0   6   0   0
1   8   9  14
2  10  12   0
3   1   0   4
4   3   0   9
```

---

If use list comprehension with `zip` shifted columns names output is different, because is compared already assigned columns `B, C...`:

```
for a, b in zip(df.columns, df.columns[1:]):
    df[b] = np.where(df[a] > df[b], 0, df[b])

print (df)
    A   B   C
0   6   0   3
1   8   9  14
2  10  12   0
3   1   0   4
4   3   0   9
```

Comment: @mozway - sure, there is mentioned it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use a vectorial approach, you cannot simply use a diff as the condition depends on the previous value being replaced or not by 0. Thus two consecutive diff cannot happen.

You can achieve a correct vectorial replacement using a shifted mask:

```
m1 = df.diff(axis=1).lt(0)               # check if < than previous
m2 = ~m1.shift(axis=1, fill_value=False) # and this didn't happen twice
df2 = df.mask(m1&m2, 0)
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0   6   0   3
1   8   9  14
2  10  12   0
3   1   0   4
4   3   0   9
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! The column C in index 0 should be 0 too!

Comment: ok, then you want the simple `diff` as proposed by jezrael but **do not use the loop**, this would give incorrect results as you modify the data